# facebook score api deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It just happened today; I am just trying to use facebook for game score leaderboard. sadly

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#games-4-4

It says:

> Games API
> Updated:
>
> Changed Instant Games context.getPlayersAsync() to only include players who have played a game in the specified context (e.g. a Messenger thread or Facebook Group).
>
> Deprecated:
>
> A number of Games APIs around scores and achievements. We are also removing the invitable friends API for Facebook web games, which allows an app to invite people who haven't played the game before. App requests for existing players of a game will continue to function normally.

Is there an alternative way to post and obtain a user's game score?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Or is there other 3rd-party platform where I can save and load a player's score?

Comment: you can program score/highscore on your own, with your own database

Comment: that's true, but that means I have to deploy server, which is somewhat a big deal to me..

Comment: you could try to use kind of "aws cognito" (or anything else similar). They have a free tier to use + you don't need to think to much about backend. There you could authorise users which did facebook login (in general there is other logins support) and then handle your scorebord. More complicated logic could be achieved with their lambda functionality. P.S. It can look complicated at first :D

Answer (score 0):

The goal would be to replace this with Leader Boards.

You can store information about the score itself.

For example, you could store the new Avg score as the value and then how many games were played to get that average.  This means that you can then update the Average correctly when you get an update. You can also create leaderboard from the API, giving you the ability to create a leaderboard per match.

To explain better I would have to have some kind of context for your game that you have and I attach below a very simple link to theleaderboard example put together by Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/guides/using-leaderboards/

Your focus would be on the other data about the score.  That is what you want to look at.  You will want to look into storing an array or JSON formatted information there.